# Convert title into tags - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I need to convert the title into tags. I want to control the length. Don't want the tag to be too short or too long, and I would also need to add a hash tag(#) in front of the tag if one doesn't exist, but clean any other character.

The code below works, but it only applies the hash tag to the first two tags.

```
$title = get_the_title($post_id);

$splittotags = explode(" ", $title);

foreach ($splittotags as $atag){

     if( strlen($atag) > 4 && strlen($atag) < 15 ){
         $first = $atag[0];

         if($first == '#'){
             $atagg = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9#]", "", $atag );
         }else{
             $atagg = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9#]", "", "#".$atag );
         }

         if($atag !=NULL){
       wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $atagg, 'post_tag', true );
         }
  }

}
```

I m also thinking of defining an array with bad tags, something like this:

```
 $not_tag = array("!", "by", "me", "auto", "mine", "by");
```

And then just do this:

```
 if( !in_array($atag, $not_tag){
```

Code runs on save_post action

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "it only applies the hash tag to the first two tags". Is your function failing to run `wp_set_object_terms` or does that function run and the tags are not assigned correctly?

I don't see any reason why your function is failing. Possibly this line, `if($atag !=NULL){`
, is not working as you expect. Perhaps [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) does not work as you think. An empty string is not NULL (`'' !== NULL`), for example.

This is untested, but I think it is a cleaner function than you have and I am pretty sure it will work.

```
$title = get_the_title($post_id);
$splittotags = explode(" ", $title);
$tags = array();
foreach ($splittotags as $atag){
  $atagg = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "", $atag ); // this will clear any existing hash characters
  if(!empty($atagg) && strlen($atagg) > 4 && strlen($atagg) < 15){
    $tags[] = '#'.$atagg;
  }
  $atagg = ''; // Clear $atagg. I'm paranoid.
}
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $tags, 'post_tag', true );
```

You may also consider using the post name-- `global $post; echo $post->post_name`-- because it will have already been cleaned. You just need to break on dashes instead of spaces.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Not sure why, but your code is doing the same. Title: `WIN Compilation June 2012 (2012/06) | LwDn x WIHEL - YouTube` Tags: `#201206 #WIHEL compilation youtube`. And if you won't mind, explain this a little for me: `$atagg = ''; // Clear $atagg. I'm paranoid.` I tried clearing all hash tags also and then adding them, but thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: I will try my code with the sample title and try to figure out the snag. The 'paranoid' part means that mostly likely the `preg_replace` line would simply overwrite the previous value of `$atagg` but I don't much like to count on that so I 'zeroed' the string explicitly.

Comment: My code with your title string gives exactly what I expected, `var_dump`ing just before `wp_set_object_terms': `array(4) { [0]=> string(12) "#Compilation" [1]=> string(7) "#201206" [2]=> string(6) "#WIHEL" [3]=> string(8) "#YouTube" }` If there is a problem it is with `wp_set_object_terms` but I don't see what. I will look around a little more.

Comment: Ok. I put the code into the functions.php of a throwaway install and was able to successfully insert the 4 tags listed in my previous post. I am not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: How are you running this function? Where are you putting it? What hook(s) are you using?

Comment: How do you have it running? Can you please show me the complete code? I added it to another function that was running on `add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post', 10, 2 );`, but I also tried it on its own. And on both tries it did the same.

Comment: I copied exactly what you see above (my code, not yours) into TwentyEleven's functions.php, except that I replaced `get_the_title($post_id)` with your sample title, `"WIN Compilation June 2012 (2012/06) | LwDn x WIHEL - YouTube"` and used an arbitrary, but real, post ID for `$post_id` in the last line. It worked like a charm. One page load and all the tags were there. I know that is not how you need to run the code but it basically eliminates the thus-far posted code as being the problem. That is why I asked what hooks you are using. Are you sure you have a valid `$post_id`.

Comment: yeah ... I also use `$post_id` for a little duplicate filter. and it works great. So that s not the problem. In my last post I noticed that the hash tag was added to 4 tags not 2. So it s getting better. :)

Comment: If the last trial added 4 tags, does that mean the problem is resolved? Why do you say "getting better"? Is something else wrong?

Comment: No, it s not resolved. It still adds just a few hashes. I don't get it. Sometimes it adds two hashes, sometimes four, sometimes three.